# VBA how do i use optional arguments in a function

Tags: excel, vba

how do i use optional arguments in Visual Basic for aplications

the following code receives a range of strings and concatonates them with a seperator.

```
Function concat(range, sep)
mystring = ""

For Each item In range
    mystring = mystring & sep & item
Next

mystring = Right(mystring, Len(mystring) - Len(sep)) 'removes preceding separator
concat = mystring
End Function
```

i want sep to be an optional argument so i can call concat(range) instead of concat(range;"")

example in python:

```
def concat(range, sep="")
    mystring = ""
    for i in range:
        mystring += sep + i
    mystring = mystring[len(sep)::]
    return mystring
```

Comment: Scott's answer should solve your problem but, in case you are interested, `mystring = Right(mystring, Len(mystring) - Len(sep))` can be re-written as `mystring = Mid(mystring, Len(sep)+1)` which might be closer to what you are used to writing in python.  (And using `Mid` will avoid an error if `myString` is empty.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to declare the types.

Use the keyword `Optional`

```
Function concat(rng As range, Optional sep As String = "")
Dim mystring As String
Dim itm As range
mystring = ""

For Each itm In rng
    mystring = mystring & sep & itm
Next

mystring = Right(mystring, Len(mystring) - Len(sep)) 'removes preceding separator
concat = mystring
End Function
```